# Constructor for different input types without code duplication in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, mapping, svcutil.exe

I have a problem with the mapping of my data class.
It contains 164 properties that are getting filled with data received from a soap web service. Dont question the property count, this is an very old predefined .csv-like data scheme that i can not change.

As far as i got it, everything works now, but since there are so many properties and I explicitly set every one of them (eg data.a1 = import.a1 OR data.a1 = export.a1) i have a big block of duplicated assignment code. Both web services deliver the same 164 fields plus some additional fields that differs for both classes. I think i only need to map the 164 identical fields and can ignore/discard the others.

What would be the correct approach to solve this problem? I thought about using 'object' or something as data type in the constructor so that i can pass data from both services, but it does not seem to work like i imagined.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
    /// <summary> Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="DataTypeTest" /> class. </summary>
    /// <param name="incomingData"> Record from Export Webservice that will be mapped to the constructed instance. </param>
    public Stddat(webExport incomingData)
    {
        // stddat fields
        this.Fields.SndRec = webExport.SndRec;
        this.Fields.PrtNum = webExport.PrtNum;
        this.Fields.MsgTyp = webExport.MsgTyp;
        .
        .
        .
    }   
    
    /// <summary> Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="DataTypeTest" /> class. </summary>
    /// <param name="incomingData"> Record from Exchange Webservice that will be mapped to the constructed instance. </param>
    public Stddat(webExchange incomingData)
    {
        // stddat fields
        this.Fields.SndRec = webExchange.SndRec;
        this.Fields.PrtNum = webExchange.PrtNum;
        this.Fields.MsgTyp = webExchange.MsgTyp;
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

Comment: does WebExchange inherit from WebExport or vice versa? (or do they both inherit from a base class with 164 common props)

Comment: They have both their own class that has been generated by svcutil.exe.
I would prefer to have just one class since it holds the same data. I found out about a command for WSDL.exe (wsdl.exe /sharetypes). This is the first time i ever work with web services and im generally "new" in the programming world so i might oversight some things. WSDL.exe seems to be no longer supported since i use .NET 6 and not .NET Framework

Comment: I suppose then you can modify the generated classes if you don't ever regenerate them.. ?

Comment: (Also, just noticed, slightly confused how your code in the constructor header has `(webExport incomingData)` but the body is `... = webExport.X` - webExport is the type? Are these statics? Or is this code a paraphrase/typo of `... = incomingData.X`

Comment: You spotted an copy / paste error there.  It has to be 'this.Fields.SndRec = incomingData.SndRec;'
Im trying to consolidate both web services into one class right now but i cant get the namespace right. I get the error : 'Namespace "urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/NxsWebservice"  in message is invalid, expected "urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/nxsexport"'.
But since the message is a server response i cant change it so i would have to dynamically change the expected namespace somehow

Comment: If you're going that route you might have to preprocess the xml text to replace the namespace/type name before you hand it over for deserializing (and I appreciate that it's not the easiest thing to do when all the functionality is wrapped up into stub classes for you

Comment: I guess i will keep that in mind for later because the solution has to go into into production after christmas :) For now i need a quick and simple solution. I managed to get AutoMapper working but i am unsure if that is better than typing all properties explicitly in the constructor. It will be easy to break something in the future without noticing, for example renaming of a field or something like that.

Comment: A mapping lib would be fine and doesn't have to be automatic; you can get, for example, Mapster to generate the c# mapping source code for you (that can then become fixed into your code) .. but that's effectively only what you've already done. The simplicity of the mapper is being able to say to it "the type represented by this.Fields is equivalent to a WebExchange" and "the type represented by this.Fields is equivalent to a WebExport" - it can then automatically do, based on property name alone, what you've laboriously done (there are ways to speed it up) 164 times with `x.SndRec = y.SndRec`

Comment: But you're right; if those names change the mapping will stop working, unless you configure it to know "WebExport.SndRec is MyType.SoundRecording" .. but but "why would the name change?" unless someone refactors, and then they should know the mapping needs to be updated.. horses for courses!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if there are that many properties this is the time i'd say a mapping software is justified.

There's the classic automapper,

> AutoMapper is a simple little library built to solve a deceptively complex problem - getting rid of code that mapped one object to another.

https://automapper.org/

But there's also Mapster:

https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster

Which has a code generation tool which may or may not be useful.

And others with all kinds of positive and negative aspects - these came to the top of my head.

Comment: I'm sure there are others too..

Comment: @CaiusJard obviously! :3

Comment: That sounds like a good idea to use an external library for this job. I guess somethink lightweight will be sufficient since i only need the mapping functionality for now. I will check AutoMapper first, since i only need the mapping functionality for now.

Comment: Yeah - use it sparringly because you lose static type checking. thats  why i found mapster interesting, it allows you to just generate the mapping code instead.

Comment: This is great, with AutoMapper i could reduce 500 lines of code to 5 lines.
Too bad that it seems like i can not post formatted code in the comments.

Comment: @sommmen Yeah indeed, i was having lunch and thought abouth advantages and disadvantages of AutoMapper. I guess i have to look at Mapster too.
I could also keep my explicit mapping because its already there but it looks just wrong to have x-hundred lines of code saying `this.Fields.SndRec = stddatImport.SndRec;`

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the generated classes so each of your X and your Y inherit the same  base, or implement the same interface that nominates 164 props then you can call one constructor from the other

```
public Stddat(BaseClass incomingData){
  //set 164 props here
}

public Stddat(WebExport incomingData) : this((BaseClass)incomingData) //set 164 props
{
  this.UniqueToWebExport1 = incomingData.UniqueToWebExport1;
  ...
}

public Stddat(WebExchange incomingData) : this((BaseClass)incomingData) //set 164 props
{
  this.UniqueToWebExchange1 = incomingData.UniqueToWebExchange1;
  ...
}
```